# Add flag in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, titles, languages, author

Is it possibile to add a flag in LaTeX?
I need to add a flag in the title page, near the title of the book.

I don't want to insert e graphic or use TiKZ

Comment: If not an external graphic or doing it within LaTeX, what else?

Comment: Why not insert it? There are a lot: http://flag-icon-css.lip.is/

Comment: You can probably have LaTeX draw the flag using LaTeX' picture-environment. With some pictures I use the filecontents*-environment for generating an encapsulated postscript-file (.eps-file) and use the `\includegraphics`-command from the graphics/graphicx bundle for including the eps-image. When using an engine that creates pdf-files, I also need the epstopdf-package with this approach.

Comment: Yet another approach I sometimes did in the past was using metafont and FontForge for creating fonts with glyphs that actually were the pictures/images that I wished to insert. For inserting a picture, I just had to change the font and type the character corresponding to the glyph that formed the image in question. This made file-sizes of pdf-files short when needing the same image several times as the image was not included several times but only once as a glyph of a font. But learning metafont is not funny at all. And images with several colors are a problem, too, with this approach.

Comment: Using a LuaLaTeX-engine and the luamplib-package, you can also insert MetaPost-code for drawing pictures/images/flags directly into your .tex-input file.

Comment: What flag? Some are easy to draw with simple tools (even just boxes), but I'd not dare with Saudi Arabia's or Brazil's.

Comment: Is there any news here?